# Youtube Blocker

Tags: python, datetime, time, module

I recently created a python project which blocks Youtube URL by making changes within the host file. I have also used Task Scheduler to automatically run the Programme as soon as I turn on my PC.

**PROBLEM:**

So what I wish to do here is to implement a feature that automatically removes the restriction on Youtube after a particular time period, say after 9 p.m. I have made an "if-else" (commented portion on my code) ready for this purpose but haven't used it as I don't know how to do it. I thought of using modules like "datetime" but didn't know how to exactly implement it here. Here is the code below:

```
#Using task Scheduler to automatically enable the programme on the startup of my computer

#import datetime
sites_to_block = ["www.youtube.com"]

hosts_path = r"C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts"
redirect = "127.0.0.1"

def block():

    #if datetime.now() < end_time:

    print("block sites")

    with open(hosts_path , 'r+') as hostsfile:

        hosts_content = hostsfile.read()
        for site in sites_to_block:
            if site not in hosts_content:
                hostsfile.write(redirect + " " + site + "\n")

    #The following will be the code after the blocktime specified by the user is over.

    '''else:
        print('unblock sites')
        with open(hosts_path,'r+') as hostsfile:
            lines = hostsfile.readlines()
            hostsfile.seek(0)
            for line in lines:
                if not any(site in line for site in sites_to_block):
                    hostsfile.write(line)
            hostsfile.truncate()
    '''

if __name__ == "__main__":
    block()
```

I don't have a good experience when it comes to using datetime module. If we can achieve using datetime, please tell me how to do it. Otherwise please do share other ways using other modules if you do know.

Thank you, I really do appreciate for reading this:)

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```py
import datetime as dt

# the blocked time intervals
intervals = [
    [dt.time(hour=0), dt.time(hour=8)],
    [dt.time(hour=21), dt.time(hour=0)],
]

# check if a pobe time is in an interval
def is_in_interval(start: dt.time, stop: dt.time, probe: dt.time) -> bool:
    if start < stop:
        return bool(start <= probe and probe < stop)
    
    elif stop < start:
        return bool(start <= probe or probe < stop)

    raise Exception("start and stop are equal")  # create your own exception
    
current_time = dt.datetime.now().time()
for interval in intervals:
    print(is_in_interval(interval[0], interval[1], current_time))
```

Comment: Hey Thanks for your solution, just saw it now. What exactly is a probe time here? Could you please explain through comments in your solution when you're free?
Your solution looks very convincing. I would really be grateful if you could explain it by editing and putting comments. Thanks @jpotyka

Comment: As you can see in the lower part of the solution the probe time is used to get set by the current_time.
That means the probe argument is the time that should be checked if it is in a blocked interval.
Or in other words, it is checked if the current_time is in a blocked interval.